# C# - Does DataTable.Merge() add duplicates or update?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, datatable, merge

I have 2 DataTables. 1 with the current rows in my table from SqlServer and 1 with new rows that I want to add.

I want to do something like:

```
datatable1.Merge(datatable2);
```

I am trying to figure out, if duplicates between these two tables exist, will the duplicate be added to datatable1, or will it update the values in datatable1?

I need for duplicates to simply be updated in datatable1, and non-duplicates to be added to datatable1.

Iv searched MSDN and I cant really find a distinct answer.

Comment: you know there are plenty of examples on how to find duplicates in a DataTable have you googled for any... I would check for duplicates first, remove those etc.. then merge your data if still necessary..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last paragraph from the [Merge documentaton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When merging a new source DataTable into the target, any source rows with a DataRowState value of Unchanged, Modified, or Deleted, is matched to target rows with the same primary key values. Source rows with a DataRowState value of Added are matched to new target rows with the same primary key values as the new source rows.

It will update any row that has the same primary key. The primary key is set by the [`DataTable.PrimaryKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Answer (score 1):

The **Remarks** section if the `Merge` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx) contains the following paragraph

> When performing a merge, changes made to the existing data before the merge are **preserved** by default during the merge operation. Developers can modify this behavior by calling one of the other two overloads for this method, and specifying a false value for the *preserveChanges* parameter.

However, the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,75b9d089d374c6a8) shows

```
public void Merge(DataTable table)
{
    Merge(table, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
}
```

i.e. it actually calls the other overload with `preserveChanges=false`.

So looks like you should be getting the desired behavior. But if you want to be absolutely sure, just call explicitly the other [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkk7s5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass `preserveChanges=false` like this

```
datatable1.Merge(datatable2, false);
```