# DataTable in DataGridView via DataSource starts duplicating data after next call

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code snippet in a backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted method. It all works perfectly, data that I am expecting shows in the DataGridView.

Updated code:

```
    private void GetResults()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

        DataTable errorTable= new DataTable();
        errorTable.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string));
        errorTable.Columns.Add("Line", typeof(int));
        errorTable.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));

        foreach (var filePath in relPaths)
        {
            SyntaxCheck sc = new SyntaxCheck
            {
                filePath = singlePath
            };

            errorTable.Merge(sc.searchFiles(), true);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = errorTable;
    }
```

`GetResults()` is called in `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted()`

As soon as I press a button that does all this again, my DataGridView updates and has 2 of each result. I do it again and it has 3 of each result. I've been going through my code for a couple hours and cannot find the error.

It looks like it just keeps appending data in the merge. If I edit my data in the files so that they shouldn't appear in the DataTable, and then press the button again, all the entries for that data are gone. Same behaviour as before keeps going on for the other data though.

All the DataTables have the same columns. I've tried calling Rows.Clear() at various points, changes nothing.

Comment: Post all the code that duplicates the problem for us.  If errorContentsFinal is new, what's the point of merging it?

Comment: You datatable errorContentsFinal is adding duplicate rows.  You have to clear the rows, otheerwise you are just adding new rows to the table.

Comment: @jdweng That's the thing, I've added `errorContentsFinal.Rows.Clear()` at different places, even simplified the code to where I only really need one datatable, added the same clear function. I also got to the point where the second loop already had 3 occurrences of each, then added a `Rows.Clear()` and back to the original problem, where it would keep adding new ones on each button press. Really strange.

I believe it could be something with the foreach loop, but no other example seems to have such issue, that I've seen atleast.

Comment: The DGV doesn't get repainted automatically.  the trick is to set dataGridView1.DataSource = null and then back to dataGridView1.DataSource =  errorContentsFinal;

Comment: @jdweng I've searched for solutions beforehand as well, tried all this already. It makes sense what you said, I've tried before and after you've mentioned it, not difference. Updated the currently used code above.

Comment: What is SyntaxCheck and what data does it hold when you call Merge into errorTable? Judging from what you have said, the likely cause is in your data being duplicated not just the UI. In addition, notice in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819752/c-sharp-does-datatable-merge-add-duplicates-or-update that Merge will not merge similar rows in different tables if their DataRowState value is Added.

Comment: @o_weisman SyntaxCheck is a class I use to gather information and add that information to a DataTable. It has the same columns as the DataTable errorTable. sc.searchFiles() returns the DataTable when done. First time all is good, second time and everytime after that, data gets appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add break points into the code and then hover over errorTable you will see a down arrow and then selecting Datatable Visualizer you will see the contents of the table.  So you can isolate where the problem by placing break points in different sections of the code until you find where the duplicates are being added.

Comment: I found the issue. As dumb as the error was, this was very frustrating. I was adding testing paths to my relPath, without clearing the list before it was called again. By debugging I was able to see that the duplication was not happening in my other class, but it was of course called an additional two times every iteration because of the paths being added to the list. I use these paths for testing purposes. When tests backfire...ouch.